# Raw Socket Programming UDP Python

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, udp

How can I add custom fields like IP and UDP headers in python in the SOCK_RAW format?I want to have a custom field in the packet and use that field in computation.

Comment: What do you mean by the `SOCK_RAW` format?

Comment: If you're planning to mess around the IP format, you need to change everything --- from the OSes to all the routers on the route.  For UDP, I'm not sure, but I think you need to as well.  Why not take the safe solution and add your field inside the UDP data?

Comment: I was talking about the raw type socket. And building the packet from scratch and editing the header fields. Thanks Mike and Rigo

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify where you want that custom field. This example lets you build the UDP header at will (at least on Linux - there might be OS-dependent behaviour):

```
from socket import *
import struct
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP)
data = 'string'
sport = 4711    # arbitrary source port
dport = 45134   # arbitrary destination port
length = 8+len(data);
checksum = 0
udp_header = struct.pack('!HHHH', sport, dport, length, checksum)
s.sendto(udp_header+data, ('', 0));
```

Tested with:

```
# socat -u UDP:localhost:4711 - &
# netstat -up
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
udp        0      0 localhost:45134         localhost:4711          ESTABLISHED 2663/socat      
# tcpdump -ilo -vv -x
11:32:07.409163 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 34)
localhost.4711 > localhost.45134: [no cksum] UDP, length 6
    0x0000:  4500 0022 0000 4000 4011 3cc9 7f00 0001
    0x0010:  7f00 0001 1267 b04e 000e 0000 7374 7269
    0x0020:  6e67
```