# How to add fields to udp packets?

Tags: python, udp, layer, scapy, network-protocols

I want to add some fields to UDP packet using scapy. I tried to write UDP class again but it did not work.  How can I add more fields to udp packets?

```
class UDP(Packet):
name = "UDP"
fields_desc=[StrLenField("omer","omer",100)]
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/24012138/840582

Comment: I didnt found answer here, i mean to create udp packet and add fields, same way as socket?

Comment: Your question is a kind open yet. So please, give more more details about the problema you are looking to solve. Give more info about your code, errors, etc.

Comment: I need to hide information in udp packets, I want to do it with add fields to a udp packets. I dont have errors because i simpaly dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet works for me. I wrote my own UDP class, which inherits from the Scapy UDP class. And then I copy, the fields_desc from UDP and add a new field. Without the copying it will change the fields of the Scapy UDP class too.

```
import scapy.all as scp

class MyUDP(scp.UDP):
    fields_desc = scp.UDP.fields_desc.copy()
    fields_desc.append(scp.StrLenField("omer","omer",100))
```

The result of `print(MyUDP().show()` is:

```
###[ UDP ]###
    sport     = domain
    dport     = domain
    len       = None
    chksum    = None
    omer      = 'omer'
None
```

I use Python 3 and scapy 3.0.0