# How do I create a raw UDP Response on Socket Webserver

Tags: python, sockets, http-headers, udp, webserver

How do I send a UDP response from the server as a webpage with the text "Here I Am !" to a Client ?

I need to write the headers and join them with the data "Here I Am !"

Here's the code that I have written so far, but I think I might have mixed up the TCP Headers and UDP headers up...

```
 ## Import socket library   UDP_server.py
import socket
#Define socket Host & Port
serverPort = 12000
serverHost = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

#Create Scoket
serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
serverSocket.bind((serverHost, serverPort))
print ("The server is ready to receive...")
print ("The web server URL: http://%s:%d/" % (serverHost,serverPort) )

#Create Response String
headers = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n'
response='''
<html>
<body>

<h1>Here I Am !/h1>

</body>
</html>
'''
def start():
    while True:
        dataClient = serverSocket.recvfrom(4096)
#        print(type(dataClient))
        print (str(dataClient))
#       print ("Connection from: ",clientAddress)

        serverSocket.sendto((headers+response).encode(),dataClient[1])

start()
```

Comment: HTTP is a TCP-based protocol, why are you trying to use it over UDP? In any case, your HTTP response is missing a `Content-Length` header.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau is the simplest HTTP Response for TCP a minimum a Status Line + Content Length + Data ( Body) only ? In that case, I will add in the missing header for my TCP Server file. For the UDP response message, will this one comment from this thread be a good example  of constructing the message ?

Comment: In HTTP over TCP, the end of the response can be signaled by closing the TCP connection, making `Content-Length` optional. If the connection is not closed, the `Content-Length` is required unless `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` or `Content-Type: multipart/...` are used (see [RFC 2616 Section 4.4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.4) and [RFC 7230 Section 3.3.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.3.3)). You don't really get that EOF option with UDP, though I suppose the datagram size can serve a similar purpose, assuming the entire response can fit in a single datagram.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau For the TCP Server Code ( not shown here) , I did add the `.close( ) ` so it make sense to omit the `Content-Length` but I think it might be good practice to have it in. Wasn't able to do the weblink earlier [UDP Raw Socket Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049143/raw-socket-programming-udp-python) this was the link I mention in my previous comment about the UDP headers