# How can I add UDP header to raw packet?

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, raw-sockets

I wish to manually add a UDP header to a raw packet which I make with a RAW socket (with `ProtocolType.IP` and NOT `ProtocolType.Udp`).

I found code in Python, [taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049143/), which did the thing I need:

```
from socket import *
import struct
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP)
data = 'string'
sport = 4711    # arbitrary source port
dport = 45134   # arbitrary destination port
length = 8+len(data);
checksum = 0
udp_header = struct.pack('!HHHH', sport, dport, length, checksum)
s.sendto(udp_header+str.encode(data), ("127.0.0.1",7070))
```

How can I do the same thing in C#?

Comment: Why would you want do this? And what code do you have so far?

Comment: I wish to implement SRT protocol for my project, for that, i also required to implement UDP protocol (I should to start building my own packet from the IP layer)

Comment: Why are you required to implement UDP, what's wrong with `UdpClient`? Don't reinvent the wheel, and if you really need to, provide a good justification for doing so. Please show relevant code, otherwise I expect your question will probably get closed as "Needs focus".

Comment: My teacher required me to build transmission layer myself, and RST uses UDP so I need to add my own UDP header. I done with it in Python (I added the code in the question)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "*My teacher required me to build transmission layer myself*" - why? Unless you are implementing your own networking stack, there is really no good reason to re-implement UDP from scratch. SRT is built on top of standard UDP, you really should use a plain ordinary UDP socket, not a RAW socket.